# x86 Assembly fcos/fsin wrong result

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

What I'm trying to do in assembly:

```
facing_x = math.cos(Pitch) * math.cos(Yaw)
```

How I do it:

```
fld qword [Pitch] 
fcos 
fst [cos]
fld qword [Yaw]
fcos 
fst [cos2]
movss xmm5,[cos] 
movss xmm7,[cos2] 
mulss xmm5,xmm7 
movss [facing_x],xmm5
```

What I always get: **1**

No matter the two inputs, I always get 1 or 0 as a result in **facing_x**

What am I doing wrong? I mean there must be something I don't understand!

Comment: Have you tried writing your code in c and see what the assembly is?

Comment: try it in debugger, but you don't release the FP stack for example, not sure how worse that will get over longer period of time (if the FP unit is set to ignore stack overflow, it's ok to use it like this). You also don't show example values, how you defined `Pitch, Yaw, cos, cos2` and where... [MCVE]

Comment: oh, and `fst` may be by default 64b or 80b precise, you didn't even write which compiler you use... but the `movss` is looking for "float", so `fst / fstp dword [cos]` would be probably safer. Again checking with debugger is the simplest way how to verify that correct amount of bytes is stored/restored and all conversions/values are as expected.

Comment: You might as well use `fmul`.  Unless you *need* to round your cos results to single-precision, there's zero point in storing them to memory and reloading with SSE1.  Like fld / fcos / fld / fcos / fmulp / `fstp dword [facing_x]`.  Note the use of `fmulp` and `fstp` to pop off the two cos results.

Comment: Please show your full code, including the definitions of `Pitch`, `Yaw`, and so on.  The snippet you showed is insufficient to correctly diagnose your problem.

Comment: @Ped7g: Are you sure you can set the FPU to ignore Stack Faults and silently overwrite valid data?  None of the bits in the x87 control word (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm#cword) do that, and the description of `fld` (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap4.htm#fld) in that detailed x87 guide doesn't mention any way around the rule that pushing a value into an in-use register will result in NaN as well as setting the SF (Stack Fault) bit in the status word.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm pretty sure, because I'm doing exactly that in my last 256B intro in the real mode and it works... I'm not sure if that's applicable also in protected mode environment with OS.  Can't exactly pinpoint it from the links you provided, and I'm too busy to search for it now, so I'm confused now too (maybe it's also special quirk of dosbox, as my intro was developed with that as target? but I have report it is working in freedos as well, although it's too slow, so maybe that's that exception handling, hm).

Comment: @PeterCordes The 80287 does care about modes which is why you need to issue `fsetpm` when switching to protected mode or weird things are going to happen.  There is no 187 or 80187 chip.

Comment: @fuz: Where is the SF mask bit?  It's not OM or IM in the x87 control word.  No exception is raised if I run this NASM code https://godbolt.org/z/qiMiRl, all 8 `st0..7` regs are NaN-indefinite after 16 iterations of the loop.  (I watched it happen in GDB with `tui reg float`).  All x87 exceptions are masked by default on Linux.

Comment: @MiH: it's often a good idea to store directions as unit vectors, rather than angles, so you don't have to compute slow functions like sin, cos, or tan.  (Or atan / asin / acos).

Comment: @PeterCordes Weird.  Perhaps I remember this incorrectly.

Comment: @fuz: Design-wise, silently overwriting registers without NaN as a sign of something gone wrong would be a Bad Thing.  It would certainly make sense if you could turn that behaviour off, but I don't think you can.  But it wouldn't be by masking an exception; you want either silent NaN or an actual exception on Stack Faults so they're easy to notice and debug.  My only experience with x87 has been on modern x86, not emulated classic 8087 or 287.  Maybe you're remembering a behaviour that used to exist but doesn't anymore?

Comment: AFAIK, @PeterCordes's observed behaviour is documented even in the original 8087 datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I want to put the answer.

Improved code:

```
finit
fld dword [Pitch]
mov dword [Math],0x42652EE1 //57.29577951308232
fld dword [Math]
fdivp st(1),st(0)
fcos
fld dword [Yaw]
fld dword [Math]
fdivp st(1),st(0)
fcos
fmulp st(1),st(0)
fstp dword [result]
```

Old code:

```
finit
fld dword [Pitch]
mov dword [Math],0x42652EE1 //57.29577951308232
fld dword [Math]
fdivp st(1),st(0)
fcos
fld dword [Yaw]
mov dword [Math],0x42652EE1 //57.29577951308232
fld dword [Math]
fdivp st(1),st(0)
fcos
fmulp st(1),st(0)
fld dword [facingX]
fxch
fcomip st(1)
fstp dword [Math]
jne l611786
fld1
jmp l412411

l611786:
fldz

l412411:
fstp dword [result]
```

Comment: code review: 1.0 and 0.0 could be stored with integer `mov` (with the right bit-pattern for `1.0`).  You don't need fld1 / fldz / fstp, just integer stuff like you're doing with `mov dword [Math],0x42652EE1`. (which you do twice, redundantly).  IDK why you're storing to a named static-storage temporary instead of using the callstack (e.g. `push 0x42652EE1` / `fld dword [esp]`), or a read-only constant that already has the right value like compilers use.  Also, you don't need to `fxch` if you're just going to use `jne`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my comment. Could you check if I did it correctly? I'm used to use [Math] a lot but I see the inconvenience

Comment: Your new code doesn't do anything with the FLAGS result of `fcomip st(1)`.  But IDK what anything in your first version of the answer had to do with the original problem of `facing_x = math.cos(Pitch) * math.cos(Yaw)`.  That doesn't need any division or comparison, and produces any real output between `[-1.0, +1.0]`, not just 0.0 or 1.0.  So yeah, your new version is closer.

Comment: Your answer comes down to "I did not realize `fcos` uses radians", even though it is documented as such: "[The source operand must be given in radians](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcos)" – and you never answered to the comment asking about the inputs `Pitch` and `Yaw` ...

Comment: The original code comes from an old project and the formula I was thinking wasn't the right formula. I'll delete my answer if you wish. (the data comes from an accelerometer)